# Дата в pandas превращается в миллисекунды

Tags: python, pandas, дата

Создаю df из CSV.
Вид df:

```
      <TICKER> <PER>    D      <TIME>   OPEN  <HIGH>  <LOW>  CLOSE    <VOL>
0    SPFB.BR     D  20100114       0  79.27   79.46  78.00  78.40    51012
1    SPFB.BR     D  20100121       0  76.42   76.79  74.29  74.50    56156
2    SPFB.BR     D  20100128       0  72.30   73.06  71.53  72.32    63514
```

Хочу создать новую колонку с номером недели.

```
dat = pd.to_datetime(df['D'])
week= dat.dt.week

Получаю:
0     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020100114
1     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020100121
2     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020100128
```

Получаю вот такой формат даты, и соответственно везде первую неделю. Почему дата превращается в миллисекунды?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите формат даты в явном виде:

```
dat = pd.to_datetime(df['D'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
```

Иначе да, оно думает, что это число и переводит его в наносекунды.

Возможно, надо ещё будет превратить данные сначала в строковый формат, надо проверять, я на всякий случай добавил это преобразование в код.